# Co-prime power modulo

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there $p$ such that $a^p\,$mod$\,r=0$  and $r$ is a prime number and $1\le a<r$.

I am believing that $a^p\,$mod$\,r=0$ will be not equal to $0$ any value of $p$ for all values of $a$ from $1$ to $r-1$.

Is it correct? please provide any counter example if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a^p\equiv 0\mod r$, it means that $r$ divides $a^p$ (or that $a^p=0$ which is not the case).

As $r$ is prime, then $r$ must divide $a$, but $a<r$ so $r$ cannot divide $a$.  This contradiction proves that the premise is false that there is $p$ such as $a^p\equiv 0\mod r$ for some $a$ with $1\le a<r$.